# Malwaranalysis with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, malware

I have a potentially malicious .apk file, which I want to analyse. I don't want to run it on my real phone, so I installed Android Studio on my Linux Computer. Can I run it without worrying or should I be careful? It could contain ransomware...

Comment: use any emulator, it should be safe

Comment: sure.if you can send me the apk, Im getting bored here wiyolu@xcodes.net